# Store console logs of IE web page in a file

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to store console logs of any IE web page in a file which I can later parse for my validation requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the console and choose "Copy all"

[image: IE Console]

You get text like this:

> ```
> HTML1200: cnet.com is on the Internet Explorer Compatibility View List ('C:\Users\colinp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml'). 
> news.cnet.com
> HTML1504: Unexpected end tag. 
> news.cnet.com, line 45 character 2212
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
> news.cnet.com, line 118 character 11
> HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document. 
> news.cnet.com, line 118 character 19
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
> news.cnet.com, line 136 character 2605
> HTML1512: Unmatched end tag. 
> news.cnet.com, line 136 character 2605
> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'stringify' 
> adtechRichMediaLib_2_15_7.js, line 8 character 94381
> TWITTER: Content Security Policy restrictions may be applied to your site. Add <meta name="twitter:widgets:csp" content="on"> to supress this warning. 
> TWITTER: Please note: Not all embedded timeline and embedded Tweet functionality is supported when CSP is applied.
> ```